# Plural for Succubus and Incubus

Tags: declension, grammar-identification, plural

Succubus & incubus don't show up in the Latin dictionaries I've searched. I'm wondering what the plurals would be. I did find succuba, 1st decl fem. Could it be that it didn't morph into a 2nd decl look-alike until it came into English? Or could it be an unusual 4th declension?

Comment: Are you looking for the plurals in English, or Latin?

Comment: English, but by way of getting clear what the Latin might be..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Wiktionary, [succubus](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/succubus) evolved in Middle English from the Latin word [succuba](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/succuba), *one who lies under*. The plural is given in the aforementioned Wiktionary as *succubi* or *succubuses*. Personally, I've usually only seen the former used (or maybe I just prefer that plural).

[Incubus](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/incubus), however, came from the late Latin word [incubus](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/incubus) which evolved from [incubo](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/incubo), *to lie upon*. The plural given by Wiktionary is the same as succubus: *incubi*, *incubuses*.

Comment: Pretty much what I was guessing.  Succuba morphed to Succubus when it came into English.  I'm with you in choosing succubi and incubi as the better plural form.

Comment: I have not yet figured out how to mark things "accepted"

Comment: Beneath the voting button should be a checkmark - click on that and it will mark that answer as accepted. You can also read more about [accepting answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) on the StackExchange meta.